# Comparision of Values from XML Files in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, xml-parsing, uml

My UML diagram is like this:

```
rootNode
   |
Book (attribute:name)
   |
Table (attribute: Name)
   |
TableEntry(attribute: Field, Value)
```

When I use this code:

```
for Book in rootNode.getBooks():
    print Book.getName()
    for Table in Book.getTables():
        print Table.getName()
        for TableEntry in Table.getTableEntrys():
            print TableEntry.getField(), TableEntry.getValue()
```

The output like this:

```
Document
T1
F1  V1
F2  V2
F3  V3
F4  V4
F5  V5
F6  V6
T2
F1 V1
F2 V2
F3  V3
F4  V4
F5  V5
F6  V6
Document
T2
F2 V2
F3  V3
F4  V4
F5  V5
F6  V6
```

I want to compare Fields and Values ex- F1 and Values V1 in Document (first) to  F1 V1 in Document(second) for every Field and Value.
I have same book name for both files  which is ‘Document’.
I also want to find missing field or additional field in both files like here in T2 my F1 and V1 is missing.

Comment: This question isn't really a good fit for SO.  Questions here should require some sort of expertise to answer your question, while your question really just requires an in-depth knowledge of your particular situation.

Comment: I Guess we can make some directories and can compare them.

Answer (score 1):

The best Solution is ' == ' to comparing the values

```
                      and
```

if you want to compare with entities then use ' is '

for example =>

a=123;
 b=123;

> > > > a is b

output:

true

Comment: and how to I get a and b, My values are in different files